# Find the Solution of $af_x + f_y = 0$, Where $a \not= -1$, and Where the Following Values Are Taken

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I have the following problem:

> Find the solution of $af_x + f_y = 0$, where $a \not= -1$, and where the following values are taken
>
> 1. $f = e^{-x^2}$ on the line $y = -x$.
> 2. $f = 1$ on the line $y = -x$
>
> For each of the above cases, what happens when $a = -1$?

---

My work is as follows:

**i)**

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = a, \frac{dy}{dt} = 1, \frac{df}{dt} = 0$$

$$\therefore x(t) = at + C_1(s), y(t) = t + C_2(s), f = e^{-x^2}$$

$$x(0) = C_1(s) = -s, y(0) = C_2(s) = 0$$

$$\therefore x(s, t) = at - s, y(s, t) = t$$

Testing transversality condition:

$$|J| = \begin{vmatrix} a& 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{vmatrix} = 0 - (-1) = 1$$

Therefore, the transversality condition holds.

**ii)**

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = a, \frac{dy}{dt} = 1, \frac{df}{dt} = 0$$

$$\therefore x(t) = at + C_1(s), y(t) = t + C_2(s), f = 1$$

$$x(0) = C_1(s) = -s, y(0) = C_2(s) = 0$$

$$\therefore x(s, t) = at - s, y(s, t) = t$$

Testing transversality condition:

$$|J| = \begin{vmatrix} a& 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{vmatrix} = 0 - (-1) = 1$$

Therefore, the transversality condition holds.

---

As can be seen, I'm confused as to how I should be solving such problems, as well as how the differences in $f$ affect these two problems and each of their solutions.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to demonstrate how these problems are solved, with explanations/reasoning for the steps of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u:=ax+y$ and $v:=x-ay$.  Then, $u$ and $v$ are independent variables (by showing that $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial v}=0$ and $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial u}=0$) such that $$x=\frac{au+v}{a^2+1}\text{ and }y=\frac{u-av}{a^2+1}\,.$$
Note that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\right)\,\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)+\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\right)\,\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)=\frac{1}{a^2+1}\,\Biggl(a\,\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)+\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)\Biggr)\,.$$
Thus, if we write $F(u,v):=f\left(\frac{au+v}{a^2+1},\frac{u-av}{a^2+1}\right)=f(x,y)$, then the equation $$a\,\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\,f(x,y)\right)+\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\,f(x,y)\right)=0$$
is equivalent to
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial u}\,F(u,v)=0\,.$$
That is, $F(u,v)=g(v)$ for some function $g$.  Consequently,
$$f(x,y)=g(x-ay)\text{ for all }x,y\,.$$

> First, suppose that $a\neq -1$.  Then, the solution $f(x,y)=g(x-ay)$ in Question (1) is given by $$g\big(x-a(-x)\big)=\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\,,$$  or equivalently $$g(t)=\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2\,(a+1)^2}\right)\,.$$  For Question (2), the solution $f(x,y)=g(x-ay)$ satisfies $$g\big(x-a(-x)\big)=1\text{ or }g(t)=1\,.$$  
>   Now, assume that $a=-1$.  Then, Question (1) is impossible, as $g\big(x-a(-x)\big)=g(0)$ is constant but $\exp\left(-\dfrac{x^2}{2}\right)$ depends on $x$.  For Question (2),  a similar logic says that $$f(x,y)=g(x-ay)=g(x+y)\,,$$ where $g(0)=1$ (and there are no other conditions on $g$).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post an answer. Where did $u:=ax+y$ and $v:=x-ay$ come from in the first place? It seems like you're using facts about the solution that you already knew, but, as someone who is new to this concept, I'm looking for a way to construct a solution from the beginning, without having memorised the facts that someone who's experienced with the concept would have. After all, I have to start somewhere in order to get there. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have to write a separate answer for two reasons---(1) MathJax is misbehaving when there are too many equations and (2) there is only a small connection between this answer and my previous answer.  The problem is here: suppose you have a partial differential equation of the form
$$a\,\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\,f(x,y)+b\,\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\,f(x,y)=0\,,$$
where $a$ and $b$ are real constants which are not both zero.  You are looking to find a new coordinate system $(u,v)$, where $u$ and $v$ are independent variables which are functions of $x$ and $y$, in such a way that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\,G(u,v)=a\,\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\,g(x,y)+b\,\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\,g(x,y)\,,$$
if $G(u,v)=g(x,y)$.  In other words, we want
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}=a\,\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+b\,\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\,.\tag{*}$$

We are making a guess here.  We suppose that $(u,v)=(px+qy,rx+sy)$ is a good coordinate system, where $p$, $q$, $r$, and $s$ are real constants with $(p,q)\neq (0,0)$ and $(r,s)\neq (0,0)$.  That is,
$$x=\frac{su-qv}{ps-qr}\text{ and }y=\frac{-ru+pv}{ps-qr}\,.$$
Because 
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=a\,\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}\right)+b\,\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)=a\,,$$
we conclude that $$\frac{s}{ps-qr}=a\,.$$
Similarly,
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}=a\,\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)+b\,\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}\right)=b$$
yields
$$\frac{r}{ps-qr}=-b\,.$$
That is,
$$ar+bs=(ps-qr)(-ab+ab)=0\,.$$

We need one last relation
$$1=\frac{\partial u}{\partial u}=a\,\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)+b\,\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)=ap+bq\,.$$
It can be seen that the pair $(u,v)=(px+qy,rx+sy)$ with $(p,q)\neq (0,0)$ and $(r,s)\neq (0,0)$ has independent variables with the required condition (*) if and only if $ap+bq=1$ and $ar+bs=0$.  One good choice is $(p,q):=\left(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2},\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}\right)$ and $(r,s)=\left(-\frac{b}{a^2+b^2},\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}\right)$. That is,
$$(u,v)=\left(\frac{ax+by}{a^2+b^2},\frac{-bx+ay}{a^2+b^2}\right)$$ is a good new coordinate system.

You can also rescale or swap the signs of $(u,v)$ above, but when you rescale $u$ and $v$, the equation (*) becomes
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}=k\,\left(a\,\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+b\,\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$$
for some constant $k$.  For example,
$$(u_1,v_1)=(ax+by,-bx+ay)$$
is also a good coordinate system.  Alternatively,
$$(u_2,v_2)=(ax+by,bx-ay)$$
is another good coordinate system.  There are infinitely many other ways to pick $(p,q,r,s)$.